# LINQ Query - Get the next row with matching parameters

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I've got a database table with the following schema:

```
id 
screenshot 
language 
projects_ID
```

I'm need to write a LINQ query, that, given an 'id', 'projects_ID', and 'language', will return the 'id' of the next row that has a matching 'projects_ID' and 'language'.

In English, my query would be:

> select the next 'id' from screenshots after the current 'id' where
>   'projects_ID' == current 'projects_ID' and language == current 'language'

Is this possible to do this via LINQ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you probably want:

```
var next = table.Where(item => item.id > lastId &&
                               item.projects_ID == projects_ID &&
                               item.language == language)
                .OrderBy(item => item.id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or as a query expression:

```
var next = (from item in table
            where item.id > lastId &&
                  item.projects_ID == projects_ID &&
                  item.language == language
            orderby item.id
            select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

The result will be `null` if there are no matches (e.g. if you're already looking at the last ID). This is assuming by "next" you mean "matching item with the lowest ID greater than the current one".

Comment: Thanks Jon - going to try this now.

Comment: How would I do the reverse? I've tried using LastOrDefault and changing the greater than to a less than, I thought that would be correct?

Comment: @JimmyC: Use `<` for the condition, but use `orderby item.id descending` and keep it using `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: I see, was looking at it the wrong way completely. Thanks once agin.